how to loop single thread multiple times with unique data for each thread and loop from csv file in jmeter
I have CSV data config file with 100 data. When I create a Thread group of 5 users I want each thread to loop 20 times and pick one unique line from CSV Data config.

For EX:
---- Loop Count = 1
Thread 1 - Loop 1 - Data 1
Thread 2 - Loop 1 - Data 2
Thread 3 - Loop 1 - Data 3
Thread 4 - Loop 1 - Data 4
Thread 5 - Loop 1 - Data 5
---- Loop Count = 2
Thread 1 - Loop 2 - Data 6
Thread 2 - Loop 2 - Data 7
Thread 3 - Loop 2 - Data 8
Thread 4 - Loop 2 - Data 9
Thread 5 - Loop 2 - Data 10
---- Loop Count = 3
Thread 1 - Loop 3 - Data 6
Thread 2 - Loop 3 - Data 7
Thread 3 - Loop 3 - Data 8
Thread 4 - Loop 3 - Data 9
Thread 5 - Loop 3 - Data 10

With default Sharing Mode of All Threads each virtual user will read next line from the CSV file on each iteration so the data will be unique.

Thread Group configuration


CSV Data Set Config configuration




This is not working as expected. Following is the behavior with this setting:
code
---- Loop Count = 1
Thread 1 - Loop 1 - Data 1
Thread 2 - Loop 1 - Data 2
Thread 3 - Loop 1 - Data 3
Thread 4 - Loop 1 - Data 4
Thread 5 - Loop 1 - Data 5
---- Loop Count = 2
Thread 1 - Loop 2 - Data 1
Thread 2 - Loop 2 - Data 2
Thread 3 - Loop 2 - Data 3
Thread 4 - Loop 2 - Data 4
Thread 5 - Loop 2 - Data 5

I want to fetch unique line from csv file by each thread on each loop.
